# Types of SQL joins

Tags: sql, join

I was doing a quiz on DBMS, and one of the questions was like:

> Which of these is an SQL join?
>
> a. Upper join
>   b. Lower join
>   c. Middle join
>   d. None

I very well know that there is no such join like middle join. Then what would the option be, upper or lower, I also tried selecting the option as none, it gave negative marks. So either a or b might be the answer and I'm not sure which one is it, didn't get any relevant answers from google too, thanks in advance if answer is known to anyone.

Comment: this is not sufficient info

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rdbms+join+types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting no relevant answers on Google because the answer is (d): None.  The closest kinds of joins are [left-join](/questions/tagged/left-join) and [right-join](/questions/tagged/right-join).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I'm doing the quiz for the second time, for the first time, I did check the option none and it gave me negative marks, so c and d probably are not the answers.

Comment: You must be checking the results wrong, as none of those are real joins. The answer must be `d`, unless the test is faulty.

Comment: Well then the test might be faulty I think so...I'll look into it.